# Making the minimum width of a layout match the inner view's width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following multiple-column layout on my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mcare="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.vodafone.mCare"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello world" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>

    ...etc...

</LinearLayout>
```

All the columns are supposed to be evenly-spaced when enough space is available.

**The goal here is to force `container1`'s (and only `container1`'s) minimum width to match the same width of its child view (`label1`)**. All the other columns should be resized evenly throughout the rest of the available space, regardless of whether there is enough space to display their contents or not. Here's a rough diagram of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried a lot of different approaches but nothing seems to work so far. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

**Edit:** Note that the layout above is just a simplified version of the actual layout on the application. All containers actually have more that one View inside them - with the exception of `container1`. In other words, only `label1` can be moved outside its respective container.

Comment: You don't need to set min_width... `wrap_content` sets minimal dimension for view. Set it for whole view tree and all the views have minimal possible width after

Comment: That's the thing... it _doesn't_ appear to set the minimal dimension of the view. Even if I set it to a specific value (say, `100dp`), the width of `container1` always seems to ignore the width of its child View.

Comment: The weight system in `LinearLayout` doesn't cover this use case. Any width specified by the children are measured _before_ distributing the weight from the remaining space.

Comment: Ah i see, my bad. If you don't need each column to have same width remove attributes that are working with weights: `weightSum`, `layout_weight`. And then set width to `wrap_content`... otherwise @corsair992 response is final...

Answer (score 0):

Remove nested `TextView` inside `LinearLayout`.

Try like this:

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="Hello world" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="Hi" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Hi" />


        </LinearLayout>

********Edited Answer*************

I have try it with `TextView` inside `LinearLayout` as well, it's working fine:

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="Hello world" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="Hi" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Without your full XML file we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that my example was just a simplified version of my layout. Each container has actually more than one view - except for the first one. I've changed my question appropriately.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what you wrote seems to be pretty much the same thing I posted above... I've tried and it doesn't work. By the way, I can't share the full layout since it has a lot of custom Views. The entire code of the app is also copyrighted.